# Can I install Unity on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, unity

I don't have any problem with GNOME, it's actualy great, but wanna testing same thing new, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backporting all the required parts was too much work for 10.10, so an option for 10.04 is highly unlikely.

However you can install an 11.04 image onto a USB stick, which would give you an option of trying it at your convenience without breaking your 10.04:

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

You can also of course use a Live CD.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can always install ubuntu 10.10 netbook remix, and choose it at login. Keep in mind that this is the netbook edition and isn't the current 11.04 progress, but it gives you the unity interface.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-unity-in-ubuntu-10-0410-10.html

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu Tweak you will see they have the Unity packages in their sources list, I have not tried Unity via this method, but if it is like the run up to 10.10 then you should be able to click the source, install the packages and then in the log in screen choose the relevant desktop environment. In 10.04 it was buggy, but you could try.

No point trying to install Natty in a virtual environment the 3D drivers do not work so Unity will not run, just defaults to the normal desktop!

Comment: Yikes no, the Unity PPA was used for testing, installing that would not be a good idea.