# How do I install Unity?

Tags: 10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Unity on 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17822/can-i-install-unity-on-10-04)

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I have no idea how to install it correctly. The command `sudo apt-get install unity` doesn't work, and I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 4):

Unity is not available for Ubuntu 10.04, you have to use at least Ubuntu 11.04 (where it is installed by default).

As support for 11.04 ends 2012-10-31 and Unity isn't that stable there anyway better use 12.04 for Unity.

Comment: AFIK, there was a ppa for 10.04